# How do I use Pycharm to step through tests that use Django and docker-compose?

Tags: python, django, pycharm, docker-compose

I'm new to Python by way of Java.  I'm getting what I would consider a classpath issue trying to use Django classes in a Pycharm project.  How do I get my project to recognize the django.contrib.auth.models package?

The following is the error message I'm getting:

```
/usr/bin/python /Applications/PyCharm.app/Contents/helpers/pydev/pydevd.py --multiproc --qt-support=auto --client 127.0.0.1 --port 49963 --file /Users/tcl/_myproject/workspace/myprojectapi/django-nonrel/myproject/integration_tests/tests/bulk_import_validation.py
pydev debugger: process 4747 is connecting

Connected to pydev debugger (build 172.3317.103)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Applications/PyCharm.app/Contents/helpers/pydev/pydevd.py", line 1596, in <module>
    globals = debugger.run(setup['file'], None, None, is_module)
  File "/Applications/PyCharm.app/Contents/helpers/pydev/pydevd.py", line 1023, in run
    pydev_imports.execfile(file, globals, locals)  # execute the script
  File "/Users/tcl/_myproject/workspace/myprojectapi/django-nonrel/myproject/integration_tests/tests/bulk_import_validation.py", line 1, in <module>
    from django.contrib.auth.models import User
ImportError: No module named django.contrib.auth.models

Process finished with exit code 1
```

I'm getting this error trying to run a test class in Pycharm by right clicking on the class and selecting debug.

The test is normally run from the cmd line using this:

docker-compose run myproject_api python manage.py test integration_tests --configuration=Dev.

Is there a way to use the Pycharm debugger to step through this code?

Comment: Are you trying to run a script directly from the Django project? There's a `manage.py` that helps you run your project.

Comment: I'm running by right clicking on the test.py file in PyCharm and selecting Debug.

Answer (score 1):

When you directly run the test, django is not loaded.

You need to right click the the `manage.py` and add the argument "test" in the configuration.

On the command line, you would execute `python manage.py test`

It is also possible to execute a specific test case indicating the test case via dot-notation, e.g.

`python manage.py test MYAPP.tests.MYTESTCASE`

For more details, please check the django documentation: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/testing/overview/#running-tests

Comment: This is what is run from the cmd line: docker-compose run myproject_api python manage.py test integration_tests --configuration=Dev. Is there a way to use the Pycharm debugger to step through this code?